# Send Smiley/Emoticons in email using javax.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, emoticons

I am trying to send smiley with text in email sent using javax.mail API.

When I sysout the unicode after unescaping, it gives correct smiley on console but in mail it displays "?" (question mark).

Here's how I am trying to do it:

Unicode String : \u0048\u0069\u0020\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE02

```
String uniMessage = "\u0048\u0069\u0020\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE02";
String message = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(uniMessage);
```

Sysout prints correct message on console as "Hi " whereas in email it is displayed as "Hi ????".

Properties props = new Properties();

```
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTPHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTPPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTPPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                password);
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(debug);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(username);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
        InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(to);
        addressTo = new InternetAddress(to);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        msg.addHeader("Demo", "Demo");
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
        Transport.send(msg);
```

Above is my mail service. How do I send smiley/emoticons correctly in email?
Please help.

Comment: The content type should also include a character encoding.

Comment: You mean it should be msg.setContent(message, "text/html; UTF-8"); ?

Answer (score 2):

It was done as suggested by @RealSkeptic as follow:

```
msg.setContent(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```